# Scaling graph with swing

Tags: java, swing, scale

I would like to know how to properly scale a graph.
I doing the axis right now, i have to represent time for the x axis that varies from 0 to 120.  The width of my component is 400.
I would like to know how to scale to have pixels from the position i give, and vice versa from the pixel how to know the position ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: This is a broad question.  Would you be a little more specific?

Comment: Ok, i m broad because i have don't really how to do it and what i need exactly to do it.  But let's say i want to draw my x axis from 0 to 120 sec, i want 0, 60 and 120 displayed for the graduation.  I want that 10px to represent 10 sec.  How would i do it ?

Comment: Every px would represent 1 second.  If you scaled it to 2px per second than every px would represent .5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have values from 0 to 120, and you want to represent this in 400 pixels.

Dividing 400 by 120 gives you 3 and 1/3 pixels per value.  You multiply the value times 3 and 1/3 to get the pixel value.

- So, a value of 30 would give a pixel value of 100.
- A value of 60 would give a pixel value of 200.
- A value of 15 would give a pixel value of 50.

Similarly, you would divide the pixel value by 3 and 1/3 to get the value.

- So, a pixel value of 100 would give a value of 30.
- A pixel value of 200 would give a value of 60.
- A pixel value of 50 would give a value of 15.